SwiftUI: Sheet disappears by itself in first time
I am facing a strange behavior of sheets. I'm using .sheet(isPresented:) to extend some data from a list. When I'm trying to call a sheet for the first time after launching it appears for a moment and immediately disappears. After that everything works correctly as it is designed. But after relaunch it starts over. Here is an extract from the code:
struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @State private var showPaymentDetails = false
    @State private var editPaymentDetails = false
    @State private var selectedPaymentActivity: PaymentActivity?

    private var paymentDataForView: [PaymentActivity]{
        //code to prepare data
    }

    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(paymentDataForView) { transaction in
                TransactionCellView(transaction: transaction)
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false, content: {
                        Button(action: {
                            // Edit payment details
                            self.selectedPaymentActivity = transaction
                            self.editPaymentDetails = true
                        }) { Image(systemName: "pencil") }
                    })
                    .onTapGesture{
                        self.selectedPaymentActivity = transaction
                        self.showPaymentDetails = true
                    }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$editPaymentDetails) {
                PaymentFormView(payment: self.selectedPaymentActivity).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.context)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showPaymentDetails) {
                PaymentDetailView(payment: selectedPaymentActivity!) .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
} 

Is it a bug or I do something wrong? Any advice or workaround is high appreciated.
I tried to use .sheet(item:content:) instead of .sheet(isPresented:), but it also works in the same way. I've also tried several approaches from related questions (for instance here and here, but they don't work as well. Moreover, I've noticed, that during the first attempt to show the sheet I have following message in the console:

Attempt to present <TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView: 0x1068fd800> on <TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier_: 0x10682c200> (from <TtGC7SwiftUI32NavigationStackHostingControllerVS_7AnyView: 0x105085e00>) while a presentation is in progress.


Can you provide a [mre]?

try sheet(item:)

At the moment you are adding sheets to every cell views, that is causing those warnings in the console. Try to move .sheet modifiers on List view like this:
        List {
        ForEach(paymentDataForView) { transaction in
            TransactionCellView(transaction: transaction)
                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false, content: {
                    Button(action: {
                        // Edit payment details
                        self.selectedPaymentActivity = transaction
                        self.editPaymentDetails = true
                    }) { Image(systemName: "pencil") }
                })
                .onTapGesture{
                    self.selectedPaymentActivity = transaction
                    self.showPaymentDetails = true
                }
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$editPaymentDetails) {
            PaymentFormView(payment: self.selectedPaymentActivity).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.context)
        }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showPaymentDetails) {
            PaymentDetailView(payment: selectedPaymentActivity!) .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        }

This will remove those warnings in console, but I am not sure that it was the reason for sheet immediate disappear.

Ivan, million thanks. Seems it was the reason. Moving the modifiers eliminated the issue and remove warnings. But the root cause is still not clear to me.

@GrigoryKonovalov i belive it has do smth with the table reuse and the cell / view getting lost after presentation... looks like a bug, but it is true that sheet presentation is better on a stable view
